# How do I make the child object not inherit a method or property from the parent object?

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods, properties

I'm creating a child object using class, but I don't want it to inherit some properties and methods from the parent object.

I want to know if there is any way to do this.

my code:

```
 class Player {
  #name;
  #marking;
  #score;
  constructor(){
   this.#name = undefined;
   this.#marking = undefined;
   this.#score = {wins:0,defeats:0};
  }
  action(){...}
  
  getName(){...}
  setName(){...}
  ...
 }

 class AIPlayer extends Player{
  constructor(){
   super();
   this.#name = "AI-0.1.2";
   
  }
  action(){...}

  //I don't want AIPlayer to inherit setName() or #score 
  
 }
  
 const p1 = new Player();
 p1.setName("Mr.Banana);
 console.log(p1.getName()); //-> Mr.Banana

 const AIP0 = new AIPlayer();
 AIP0.setName("stupid computer"); //->error
 console.log(AIP0.getName()); //-> AI-0.1.2
```

Comment: "*I don't want it to inherit some properties and methods*" - then you don't want to use [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) at all, if an `AIPlayer` [is not a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Player`. Maybe what you actually want is a `Player` base class from which a `RenamablePlayer` and an `AIPlayer` inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

Just overload method:

```
setName(name) {
  throw "AI player name can't be modified."
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the best thing to do in this case, I just want him not to inherit this method.

Comment: @JEmerson23 I'm afraid then there is no way to delete a method from the ancestors. A method that is public will always exist on its descendants, otherwise it would violate the inherent paradigm of class extension. You would instead have to implement a new class from scratch or using a common 'minimal' parent instead that would not define the method.

Comment: @Bergi proposes a similar approach to the that. Either way, extending the method will be possible, you can not prevent it technically.

Answer (score -2):

The way I found to "delete" the method without using overhead was as follows:

```
 class Child extends Parent{
  constructor(){
   super();
   this.methodYouWantToDelete = null;
   ...
  }
 }
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do this, but it works.

Comment: if you dont want to inherit property always use encapsulation concept, or create abstract class/methods.